# Apache Client 4.x close a HttpRequestBase

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to create a method called close() that when called will release the connection for an HttpRequestBase that I have called httpMethod. My issue is that the code below would have worked perfectly fine in Client 3.x but it doesn't work with Android API 21 which uses a version of Client 4.x so my question is how do I get this to properly close the connection

```
public void close() {
    ExecutorService es =(ExecutorService) CallableSingleTon.getExecutor();
    es.shutdown();
    if (null != httpMethod) {
        httpMethod.releaseConnection();
        //postMethod.abort();
    }
    httpMethod = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be something like this:

```
try{
  CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, http_req, localContext);
  response.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);
  // read the entire stream to end in order to reuse connection
  EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}finally{
   response.close();
}
```

When the http client is no longer need you can execute `httpclient.close();` which terminates all open connections.
The Client 4.x is quite different than Client 3.x, so I guess you will need some more refactoring.